# MySQL insert with jQuery Validate Plugin

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, insert

I'm trying to insert some data with jQuery Validate (http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and PHP but can't seem to get it to work.
I have tried 20 different things but without luck. Maybe it's just my lack of knowledge with jQuery, but that's why I'm here for help, so any sort of help is much appreciated.
Here's the code:

**add_news.php**

```
<?php include('_header.php'); ?>

<p>
    <form id="addnews" name="addnews" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
        <fieldset>
              <label for="headline" id="headline">Overskrift</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="headline" required="">

              <label for="img1" id="img1">Billede 1</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="img1" required="">
              <label for="img2" id="img2">Billede 2</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="img2" required="">
              <label for="img3" id="img3">Billede 3</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="img3" required="">

              <label for="article" id="article">Nyhed</label>
              <textarea style="text-align:left;" name="article" class="form-control" required=""></textarea>
              </br>
              <input class="btn form-control" type="submit" name="submit" value="Tilføj">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div id="success">
        <span class="green textcenter">
            <p>Nyheden er blevet tilføjet.</p>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="error">
        <span>
            <p>Der skete en fejl. Prøv igen.</p>
        </span>
    </div>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

// validate contact form
$(function() {
    $('#addnews').validate({
        rules: {
            headline: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            img1: {
                required: true,
                extension: "png|jpg|gif"
            },
            img2: {
                required: true,
                extension: "png|jpg|gif"
            },
            img3: {
                required: true,
                extension: "png|jpg|gif"
            },
            article: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 50
            }
        },
        messages: {
            headline: {
                required: "Du skal skrive en overskrift",
                minlength: "Overskriften må ikke være under 5 tegn"
            },
            img1: {
                required: "Du skal indsætte et billede",
                extension: "Tilladte formatter: PNG, JPG, GIF"
            },
            img2: {
                required: "Du skal indsætte et billede",
                extension: "Tilladte formatter: PNG, JPG, GIF"
            },
            img3: {
                required: "Du skal indsætte et billede",
                extension: "Tilladte formatter: PNG, JPG, GIF"
            },
            article: {
                required: "Du skal skrive en nyhed",
                minlength: "Nyheden skal være på minimum 50 tegn"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            var headline=$("#headline").val();
            var img1=$("#img1").val();
            var img2=$("#img2").val();
            var img3=$("#img3").val();
            var article=$("#article").val();

            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                type:"POST",
                url:"add_news_process.php",
                dataType: "text",
                data: "headline="+headline+"&img1="+img1+"&img2="+img2+"&img3="+img3+"&article="+article,                
                success: function() {
                    $('#addnews :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#addnews').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                        $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                        $('#success').fadeIn();
                    });
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#addnews').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                        $('#error').fadeIn();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

<?php include('_footer.php'); ?>
```

**add_news_process.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    try {
        $date = date('d/m/Y');
        require_once('config.php');
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $insertNews = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO news VALUES (NULL, STR_TO_DATE(':datec', '%m/%d/%Y'), :head, :img1, :img2, :img3, :article)");
        $insertNews->bindValue(':datec', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertNews->bindValue(':head', $_POST['headline'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertNews->bindValue(':img1', $_POST['img1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertNews->bindValue(':img2', $_POST['img2'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertNews->bindValue(':img3', $_POST['img3'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertNews->bindValue(':article', $_POST['article'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertNews->execute();

        echo 'Nyhed tilføjet.';

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

The result of this process is this being called: `error: function(){}`

I hope I explained myself clearly. If not then let me know.

Comment: try adding three different variables to the error: function() (something like function(a,b,c)) which are usually the errors that ajax requests give back and seeing what those errors state in a javascript debugger (i.e. Chrome)

Comment: Were you able to fix it?